# Set height and width of custom view according to xml

Tags: android, view

I have successfully made a custom PinView class.
Now the problem is I want to set the pin view buttons size according to PinView size that is specified in XML. Like a button would have 5% width and height of PinView.

currently, I am setting PinView height and width by doing this `getPinPadHeight()` is returning 80% of screen height and 70% of screen width

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    pinView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewUtil.getPinPadHeight();
    pinView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewUtil.getPinPadWidth();
}
```

but now the problem is this when I use this custom PinView view in my main activity XML file like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/parent_view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <production.kado.lock.views.PinView
         android:id="@+id/pinView"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true"
         android:layout_width="300dp"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         app:changePassword="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and i want to change its height and width its not changing its always set according to screen height and width percentage how can i make this view like some library so i can  set height and width according to my preference and views inside it automatically measure themselves accroding to xml attributes when I will use this custom view

```
public class PinView extends RelativeLayout {
    public PinView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView();
    }

    public PinView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        initView();
    }

    public PinView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        pinView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewUtil.getPinPadHeight();
        pinView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewUtil.getPinPadWidth();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pierre onMeausre is calling too many times and every time it's giving diff height and width can you please explain little bit more with some example

Comment: Well, first.. what does `ViewUtil.getPinPadHeight()` return?

Comment: So the problem is, you have to have a way to see whether the pinView is set to match_parent or has a dp width/height. You can add another attribute for the pinview called customsize, if it is true, it means custom width/height dp was used, if false then use your `ViewUtil.getPinPadHeight/Width()`

Comment: @Pierre `public static int getPinPadHeight() {
        return (int) (AppUtils.getScreenHeight() * 70 / 100);
    }` i am calculating percnetage of screen sizes

Comment: ok, Thanks i got your point and please tell should i do this in `onAttachedToWindow()` method?

Comment: ok let me check i'll update Thank you

Comment: did the solution work?

Answer (score 0):

What about doing your calculations inside onSizeChanged?

Answer (score 0):

Add another attribute to `Res/values/attrs.xml`

```
<declare-styleable name="PinView">
    <attr name="changePassword" format="boolean" />
    <attr name="customSize" format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In your constructors with attributes, retrieve the customSize boolean

```
TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.PinView, 0, 0);
//Set CustomSize boolean Global Variable
customSize = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.PinView_customSize, false);
```

then change your `onAttachedToWindow` method:

```
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    if(!customSize) {
        pinView.getLayoutParams().height = ViewUtil.getPinPadHeight();
        pinView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewUtil.getPinPadWidth();
    }
}
```

In this way, if `app:customSize="true"` then it will skip the `ViewUtil.getPinPadHeight()` and `ViewUtil.getPinPadWidth()`